# Parsing human readable intervals in Java

Tags: java, date, intervals

Many applications support human-readable intervals like 20d, 1y, 2m1d etc.

Is there an established best practice for parsing those? Experience teaches that, with our whacky calendars being what they are, time parsing usually holds traps galore for the unwary traveler.

Comment: I think you're looking for [`java.time.Duration`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Duration.html).

Comment: Yes: these are not intervals, but durations.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch While `Duration` is suitable for holding the data and does support parsing, it only supports a syntax it describes itself as `PnDTnHnMn.nS`, which is at least 
slightly less *human readable* than the given examples.

Comment: @Izruo Mechanically transforming and then using the built-in parser is one option. As is parsing with custom code. Either way, using the built-in type is likely to be easier than starting from scratch.

Answer (score 1):

## *java.time*

Use the *java.time* classes built into Java 8 and later. These supplant the terrible legacy date-time classes.

### `Period`

Among those classes is `Period`, to represent a span of time unattached you the timeline on a scale of years-months-days.

## ISO 8601

That class uses the standard [ISO 8601 format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Durations) when parsing/generating text: `PnYnMnDTnHnMnS`. The `P` Mark’s the beginning, and the `T` separates any years-months-days from any hours-minutes-seconds.

```
String input = "P2M1D" ;
Period p = Period.parse( input ) ;
```

If you have non-standard inputs such as `20d` you may be able to do some simple string manipulation to comply with the standard.

```
String input = "20d" ;
String modified = "P" + input.toUpperCase() ;
Period p = Period.parse( modified ) ;
```

## *ThreeTen-Extra*

To represent a span of time that is attached to the timeline, add the *ThreeTen-Extra* library to your project. Use its `LocalDateRange` class to represent a pair of `LocalDate` objects, along with handy comparison methods such as `contains`, `abuts`, etc.

Comment: You don’t need the call to `toUpperCase()`. `Period.parse()` parses case insensitively.